# Pandas outputting with column names in rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the below script, which does what I need. Except, the Pandas dataframe has one row for each column like below. Title, Excerpt and url should be the column names

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
#Get post titles & links
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.DataFrame([])

    for container in post_containers:
        # find the first <a> tag and get the text. Split the text using '/' to get an array with developer name and repo name
        container_name = container.find(class_="elementor-post__title").text.split('>')[0].strip()
        for link in container.find_all('a'):
            link = link.get('href')  
        excerpt = container.find(class_="elementor-post__excerpt").text.split('>')[0].strip()    
        d = {'title': container_name, 'excerpt': excerpt, 'url': link}
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()))
        raw_data = raw_data.append(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is representative of above,

one idea is set your first col to index then transpose.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0 : ['title', 'excerpt','url'],
             1 : ['title1', 'excerpt1','url1'],
             2 : ['title2','excerpt2','url2']})
print(df)
         0         1         2
0    title    title1    title2
1  excerpt  excerpt1  excerpt2
2      url      url1      url2



df_new = df.set_index(0).T

print(df_new)
    title   excerpt   url
0  title1  excerpt1  url1
1  title2  excerpt2  url2
```